# How to ignore the websocket event for the client who made a change via HTTP?

Tags: reactjs, rest, http, websocket, architecture

We have a React application which uses REST to get and update data and Websocket to receive notifications of changes.

Imagining we have a collections /users

1. user1 calls the http method POST /users to create a new user
2. user1 receives positive http response and the created user is added to the UI list.
3. user1 also receives Websocket notification "user:created" and again trying to add a new item to the UI list.

So, the user who made a call should process the result twice because of HTTP response and because of WS event. That is what I trying to fix.

Few possible solutions:
1. Skip WS event for the user who called POST /users. The problem he could have a few open browser tabs. And all of them will not be updated.
2. Do not process HTTP responses, process WS events only.

Have anybody experienced such a problem? What other solutions available?

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean by point 3? user1 receives a ws event, react then tries to create the user once more?

Answer (score 3):

You've basically pointed out best solution (2.) but here are some options

1. Don't use response from POST, but rather wait for "user:created" event that would updated list for all subscribed clients (including one that initiated POST) - **suggested approach**
2. Use your current implementation but your POST and "user:created" event should share some kind of identifier that they return along with rest of the request which client can use to determine whether he already got that information or not - e.g. "user:created:{userId}". Then only client that don't have "user:created:{userId}" in memory would use WS event data. - not recommended
3. Skip WS event for user that initiated POST - problem with this is if specific user has multiple clients (tabs, browser + mobile, etc) connected - with this approach you'd have to skip the WS event for the client (connectionId in socket terms) that initiated POST request (not user!). So if user has 10 connections, you'd send "user:created" event to 9 connections except the one that initiated request + all other connections that should receive that event - not recommended since it complicates your backend a lot.

In my opinion easiest and cleanest way is to just ignore POST response and wait for that WS event - since those are sockets you shouldn't have any UI problems or delays.

Answer (score 0):

If the client which has added a user emits the event, then use

```
// sending to all clients except sender
  socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast', 'hello friends!');
```

This will not emit the event to the client and you can have logic in your react app to listen to the socket event as well as the response of the http request.
This will prevent the duplication or bad data.

If there are multiple tabs open for the same client, the client tab which intiated the http request will update the state list with the http response and all other user's tabs or other users will receive the socket event.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add a "idempotency counter" field in a request. Basically it is just a number, which is incremented for each request, and is stored on a frontend side. Backend would need to answer with the same counter for each successful request.

Your processing logic would look like:

```
function onUserAdded(user, counter) {
  if(current_counter < counter) { 
    console.log("User added");
    current_counter++;
  } else {
    console.log("User not added");
  }
}
```

- `current_counter=0`
- Call `POST /users`, with `counter = current_counter + 1`, get response with `counter=1` -> `User added`
- Get websocket notification with `counter=1` -> `User not added`